# RegEx: Is there a way to ignore a specific set of characters in a string and still match?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have some music files organized (poorly) by artist name, for example:

```
/data/myfolder/Jay Z/some_file1.mp3
/data/myfolder/Jay-Z/some_file2.mp3
/data/myfolder/JayZ/some_file3.mp3
/data/myfolder/Destiny's Child/some_file4.mp3
/data/myfolder/Destinys Child/some_file5.mp3
```

I want to run some batch operations using regex matching. However, I want to ignore the special characters within the artist's names when finding my matches. I could *programmatically* replace special characters with python, but I'm wondering if its possible to do it *completely with the regex pattern*.

For example, the following code would only work on `some_file1.mp3` and `some_file4.mp3` as it is currently written:

```
import os
import re

artists = ["Jay Z", "Destiny's Child"]
root = "/data/myfolder/"

for filepath in os.listdir(root):
    for artist in artists:
        pattern = r"\/data\/myfolder\/{}\/.*.mp3".format(artist)
        match = re.search(pattern, filepath)

        if match:
            ...do some stuff...
```

Is there some way to modify my regex pattern from `/\/data\/myfolder\/{}\/.*.mp3.format(artist)`  so that it would successfully match even when there is a dash, single quote, or other specified special character within the string?  Basically, I'm trying to ignore the presence of certain characters anywhere in a string when looking for a match.

Comment: For the cases you've shown, I would suggest you use the regex to delete those characters. Replace them with nothing. Although python is not something I use regularly enough to come up with a code sample.

Comment: How do you define "special characters"? In your example it's clearly an apostrophe but are there others?

Comment: @Vlad although I'm using the term "special characters" what I really mean is a set of predefined characters that I imagine would come up in such a situation (artist names). So I would say apostrophe, dashes, periods, and commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, your `for filepath in os.listdir(root)` returns the list of subfolfders inside `root`, but not the files in them. You need to use `os.walk`:

```py
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    if not dirnames:
        for filename in filenames:
            filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```

Now, if you want to use a regex that ignores any chars of your choice inside some fixed string used as part of a regex, you can only try the fuzzy matching capabilities of the [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/). The idea is to remove all the ignored chars from the `artists` items, and then allow any amount of these character insertions in the artist subfolder part.

See the Python code:

```py
import regex, os
artists = ["Jay Z", "Destiny's Child"]
artists = [regex.sub(r"[',. -]+", "", s) for s in artists]
root = r'/data/myfolder'

        
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    if not dirnames:
        for filename in filenames:
            filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            for artist in artists:
                pattern = r"{}[\\/](?:{}){{i:[',. -]}}[\\/][^\\/]*\.mp3$".format(regex.escape(root), artist)
                match = regex.search(pattern, filepath)
                if match:
                    print(match.group())
```

Note the `[\\/]` is used to match both Windows and Linux folder separators. I also added a space to the list of ignored chars.

The `artists = [regex.sub(r"[',. -]+", "", s) for s in artists]` is the prep step to remove ignored chars from the `artists` subfolder names.

The regex looks like `/data/myfolder[\\/](?:DestinysChild){i:[',. -]}[\\/][^\\/]*\.mp3$`:

- `/data/myfolder` - a literal root part
- `[\\/]` - a `/` or `\` char
- `(?:DestinysChild){i:[',. -]}` - `DestinyChild` string with any amount of space, apostrophe, hyphen, dot or comma insertions
- `[\\/]` - a `/` or `\` char
- `[^\\/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/` and `\`
- `\.mp3$` - `.mp3` at the end of string.

Answer (score -1):

put it inside bracket `[{}]+`, I know it could return unwanted result, for example regex `[Jay Z]` will match `Jay Z`, `JayZ`, `ZJ`, or even just `Z`, but I think this is the best way if you don't want to `replace or modify the code`.

```
pattern = r"\/data\/myfolder\/[{}]+\/.*.mp3".format(artist)
```